# Query speed in SQL Server Management Studio (2008) vs NHibernate session.Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq, nhibernate

I have the following query in SSMS2008:

```
select *
from Measurements
where dt > '2016-01-01 04:00:00'
  and dt < '2016-01-01 04:05:00'
  and classification = 'heartbeat'
```

My table has over 400 million records in it, heartbeats and other data *(I know)*, but above query executes in less than 1 second *(retrieves around 1500 records)*. There are indexes on the dt and classification column.

When I use this query in NHibernate:

```
var heartbeats = session.Query<Measurements>()
                        .Where(m.dt > dtFr &&
                               m.dt < dtTo &&
                               m.classification = 'heartbeat')
                        .ToList();
```

.. however, this query fails. The only thing that is different *(as far as I can see)*, is that I use DateTime objects *(`dtFr` and `dtTo`)* and pass them to the linq expression. However, when this query fails (Timeout), I can copy + paste the failed query to SSMS2008 and it will execute there without any problems.

Edit: yesterday I did way too much testing and I got things mixed up. It seems like the failed query does NOT run *(neither from SSMS)*. I can't see what I do wrong.

Comment: So what's the question now? Hard to help you when you don't know what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1):

There is missing information about mapping, which at that moment seems to be the most suspected. Namely in case, that there are related references, with some not standard fetching *(not lazy, which is default and in fact the best)*

To fix *(or maybe to avoid)* such issue, use projection. That way, NHibernate will load and later process just required fields

```
var heartbeats = session.Query<Measurements>()
    .Where(m.dt > dtFr &&
        m.dt < dtTo &&
        m.classification = 'heartbeat')
    .Select( x => new {m.dt, m.classification })
    .ToList();
```

Other words, the difference between raw SQL and Final processing with NHibernate... is usually **materialization**. Be sure, that you reduce that here... and results should be fast as a direct SQL execution

Answer (score 0):

I probably would say that the first select is processed on the sql server. (Obviously as you have tested it with the Management Studio)

I think what happens is that the query in the code requests all data from the sql server and afterwards it does the search in your local application.

I might be wrong as I don't know how linq processes a where clause but it sounds to me as if this might be the case.

Cheers

Thomas